# BreezeJs and Chrome 33

Tags: google-chrome, breeze

BreezeJS throws the following error on Chrome:

> [Q] Unhandled rejection reasons (should be empty): 
>   ["Error: Illegal construction - use 'or' to combine …tp://localhost:6592/Scripts/breeze.min.js:5:9573)"]
>   0: "Error: Illegal construction - use 'or' to combine checks↵    at m (localhost:6592/Scripts/breeze.min.js:1:11658)↵    at r.isOptional (localhost:6592/Scripts/breeze.min.js:1:13100)↵    at k.getKey (localhost:6592/Scripts/breeze.min.js:2:5019)↵    at M [as _$interceptor] (localhost:6592/Scripts/breeze.min.js:1:7492)↵    at a.splice.h.computed.write (localhost:6592/Scripts/breeze.min.js:5:30754)↵    at dependentObservable [as id] (localhost:6592/Scripts/knockout-2.3.0.debug.js:1298:31)↵    at a.setProperty (localhost:6592/Scripts/breeze.min.js:5:31148)↵    at localhost:6592/Scripts/breeze.min.js:3:11420↵    at Array.forEach (native)↵    at q._updateTargetFromRaw (localhost:6592/Scripts/breeze.min.js:3:11058)↵    at k (localhost:6592/Scripts/breeze.min.js:5:9573)"
>   1: "Error: Illegal construction - use 'or' to combine checks↵    at m (localhost:6592/Scripts/breeze.min.js:1:11658)↵    at r.isOptional (localhost:6592/Scripts/breeze.min.js:1:13100)↵    at k.getKey (localhost:6592/Scripts/breeze.min.js:2:5019)↵    at M [as _$interceptor] (localhost:6592/Scripts/breeze.min.js:1:7492)↵    at a.splice.h.computed.write (localhost:6592/Scripts/breeze.min.js:5:30754)↵    at dependentObservable [as id] (localhost:6592/Scripts/knockout-2.3.0.debug.js:1298:31)↵    at a.setProperty (localhost:6592/Scripts/breeze.min.js:5:31148)↵    at localhost:6592/Scripts/breeze.min.js:3:11420↵    at Array.forEach (native)↵    at q._updateTargetFromRaw (localhost:6592/Scripts/breeze.min.js:3:11058)↵    at k (localhost:6592/Scripts/breeze.min.js:5:9573)"
>   length: 2
>   **proto**: Array[0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Updated 3/1/2014

Ok, we think that this is fixed in Breeze v 1.4.9 ( or later) available now.

### Previous post

This is a problem that we have been tracking.  It appears to occur only on the minified version of Breeze in Chrome 33.  We are planning a fix for later this week.  Until then try using the unminified version.